# What is a reasonable use case for the Python package sympy.physics.units?

Tags: sympy, physics

I was investigating the use of sympy to work physics problems. For my use case, I was focusing on Schroedinger's equation in Gaussian electrical units. I tried to use the package mentioned in the question title but was unsuccessful. THe difficulties left me wondering if this was the right package. In the answers below, someone suggested an alternate package. of charge). I have the following code

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *
from sympy.physics.units import Quantity
from sympy.physics.units.systems.cgs import cgs_gauss
from sympy.physics.units import convert_to, charge, elementary_charge, coulomb
from sympy.physics.units import Quantity, coulomb
q = Quantity("elementary_charge")

cgs_gauss.set_quantity_dimension(q,charge)


q1=convert_to(q,coulomb, unit_system='cgs_gauss')

display(q1)
q1.n()
```

This gives the result 3.33564095198152⋅10−5C, which is not useful because it is in Coulombs rather than statcoulombs.

The corresponding code fails because statcoulomb is undefined.

```
q1=convert_to(q,statcoulomb, unit_system='cgs_gauss')
```

Examining the symbols exposed by physics.units does not reveal any symbol for this purpose. I wonder if I am missing something, or if this gap appears because the module is unfinished and still under development

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna have a look at [scipy.constants](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/constants.html).

you could try:

```
from scipy.constants import e
```